# creating an NSViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Probably a very simple question. I'm trying to create a series of circles that would be like checkboxes or change colour when you click them. Just to begin I'm trying to initialise a rectangle. I've read that it needs to be an NSView subclass but I'm not sure what that is because it's not an option in the Objective-C class list. Which subclass should I use?

Comment: NSView is for OSX development.  The iPhone rough equivalent is UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSView` is for OS X development.

`UIView` is its iOS counterpart.

### Use `UIView`.

In fact, you'll find this relationship true of many UI classes:

- `NSView` > `UIView`
- `NSTableView` > `UITableView`
- `NSSlider` > `UISlider`
- `NSTextField` > `UITextField`
- And on and on and on...

Comment: Nothing on the Mac translates over easily like this (AppKit almost never ports straight to UIKit as you seem to be implying).  Also, what's an NSLabel?  Surely you mean NSTextField.

Comment: @CodaFi It might not be easy, but it's a fairly certain guess that a `UITableView` does about the same thing as a `NSTableView`

Comment: @Undo About the same thing?  NSTableView has nothing in common with UITableView!  View-based tables are a hack they implemented in 10.7 to make our lives easier.

Comment: @CodaFi I'm talking about end result. Implementation, no.

Comment: I'm pretty much following someones tutorial but I don't see a circle drawn.  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
         CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(200.0, 200.0, 200.0, 100.0);
        CGContextAddRect(ctx, rect);
        CGContextFillPath(ctx);
        [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
        UIBezierPath* circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [circlePath appendBezierPathWithOvalInRect: rect];
        [circlePath fill];
        [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
        [circlePath stroke];

Comment: in a (void) drawRect:  ...{}   function in my .m of a UIView subclass